# partial не добавляет form_for на страницу

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Имеется partial(_income_category.html.erb)
Имеется главная страница(index.html.erb)
Имеется JS(create.js.erb)
Ссылка на проект - https://github.com/rozen90/project1
Суть проблемы: после вызова create.js.erb к index.html.erb на страницу добавляется только часть partial(_income_category.html.erb)

```
<tr id="income_category_<%= income_category.id %>">
<td><%= link_to income_category.title, income_category_incomes_path(income_category) %></td>
<td><%= income_category.description %></td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle=modal data-target="#thisupdate_income_category_<%= income_category.id %>">Edit</button> </td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', income_category, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-warning' %></td>
```

Но не происходит добавления

```
<%= form_for(income_category, :method => :put, remote: true) do |f| %>
<div class="modal fade" id="thisupdate_income_category_<%= income_category.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit</h4>
   </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="myupdatebutton_<%= income_category.id %>" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <%= submit_tag "Edit", class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: При объединении всего partial тегом <div> </div> вообще напрочь отказывается видеть html теги в partial, но добавляется form_for к разметке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть ответ сервера, то видно, что все рендерится. Проблема в том, что нельзя вставить `div` между `tr` таблицы, поэтому браузер их игнорирует.

То что у вас работают эти модальные окна, когда вы загружаете страницу, виноват опять же браузер - он за вас исправляет разметку. Посмотрите исходный код и сравните с тем, что отображается в инспекторе: Firefox, например, выносит все модальные окна за таблицу.

**Выход**: можно, например, модальное окно вложить в последнюю ячейку таблицы:
`_income_category.html.ebr`

```
<tr id="income_category_<%= income_category.id %>">
  <td align="center"><%= link_to income_category.title, income_category_incomes_path(income_category) %></td>
  <td align="center"><%= income_category.description %></td>
  <td align="center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle=modal data-target="#thisupdate_income_category_<%= income_category.id %>">Edit</button> </td>
  <td align="center"><%= link_to 'Destroy', income_category, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-warning' %>

    <%= form_for(income_category, method: :patch, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <div class="modal fade" id="thisupdate_income_category_<%= income_category.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        ...
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </td>
</tr>
```